# No Names returned in search function

Tags: c++, arrays, object

So I cant get my search function to return to the actual title of the movies with the instantiated array with a movie title, director, and actor. I create an array of objects, instantiate it, run a do while loop to get the position, and run a search algorithm to get the title, director, and actor of the movie. But for the life of me I cant get the code to return the actual title, director or actor. It will say the name is in the list, but returns an empty space. I linked a picture below to show the return. When I add a movie to the array it says the movie does not exist in the array.

The movie Class:

```
class Movies{
private:

    // variables
    string titleCode;
    string directorCode;
    string actorCode;

public:

    // constructors
    Movies()        // default constructor, allows no arguments.
    {
        //titleCode = "Home Movie"; directorCode = "Colin Powers"; actorCode = "Colin Powers";
    }
    Movies(string t, string d, string a) // constructor
    {
        titleCode = t; directorCode = d; actorCode = a;
    }

    // getter
    string getTitle() const
    {
        string title = titleCode;
        return title;
    }
    string getDirector() const
    {
        string director = directorCode;
        return director;
    }
    string getActors() const
    {
        string actors = actorCode;
        return actors;
    }

    // setters
    void setTitle(string t) // cout/cin were giving random "ambigious" error so i added std:: till they all stopped giving it.
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the title of the Movie: " << endl;
        std::cin >> t;
        titleCode = t;
    }
    void setDirector(string d)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the Director of the Movie: " << endl;
        std::cin >> d;
        directorCode = d;
    }
    void setActors(string a)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the main protagonist: " << endl;
        std::cin >> a;
        actorCode = a;
    }};
```

---

Movies Array:

```
Movies moviesArr[ARR_SIZE];
```

Function prototype for the search function

```
int searchMovies(const Movies[], int, string);
```

Instantiated array of objects to search through

```
Movies hollywood[ARR_SIZE] =
{ // title, director, actor
    Movies("Avatar", "James", "James"),
    Movies("Terminator", "John", "John"),
    Movies("Predator", "Michael", "Michael")
};
```

Do while to get returned position and names:

```
do
                {
                    // get the movie title
                    cout << "Enter the movie title to search: " << endl;
                    cin >> title;

                    // search for the object
                    pos = searchMovies(hollywood, ARR_SIZE, title);

                    // if pos = -1 the title was not found
                    if (pos == -1)
                        cout << "That title does not exit in the list.\n";
                    else
                    {
                        // the object was found so use the get pos to get the description
                        cout << "The movie: " << moviesArr[pos].getTitle() << " is in the list. " << endl;
                        cout << "It was Directed by: " << moviesArr[pos].getDirector() << endl;
                        cout << "It also stars: " << moviesArr[pos].getActors() << endl;
                    }

                    // does the user want to look up another movie?
                    cout << "\nLook up another movie? (Y/N) ";
                    cin >> doAgain;

                } while (doAgain == 'Y' || doAgain == 'y');
```

Search function to search array:

```
int searchMovies(const Movies object[], int ARR_SIZE, string value){
int index = 0;          
int position = -1;      
bool found = false;     

while (index < ARR_SIZE && !found)
{
    if (object[index].getTitle() == value)  // if the title is found
    {
        found = true;       // set the flag.
        position = index;   // record the values subscript
    }
    index++;                // go to the next element.
}
return position;            // return the position or -1;}
```

output looks like:
[Nondescrip return, no names, no director, no title.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbqgL.png)

Comment: You're searching in `hollywood`, but printing `moviesArr`?  What is `moviesArr` anyway?

Comment: Ah, and the definition of `moviesArr` doesn't seem here. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your set functions appear to take value type arguments. So their values are discarded on function return. You'll need to pass by reference to the setters. Or maybe not. Am totally confused as to what they do to be honest.

Comment: @systemcpro Erm, actually, no.  The setters are fine.

Comment: @Paul Sanders. Fair enough. Am totally confused as to what those arguments actually do.

Comment: @systemcpro A string is passed by value (i.e. a copy is made) and then assigned to the member variable (so another copy is made).  Maybe one of these copies can be elided, I'm not sure. Anyway, by hook or by crook, a copy of the string passed in ends up in the member variable, as intended.

Comment: @MikeCAT I posted the definition of moviesARR. the entirety of the code is about triple this length, but if I can get the movies section to work, i get the the other sections to work as they are similar just labeled different (IE "books", "music", etc).

Comment: @PaulSanders I understand your confusion. I am following the "Starting out with C++ Early objects" by Gaddis and this is the way he does it in the books, but I cant get it to function.

Comment: Your posted code is not complete. There is high chance that the cause is that your program is fetching information from the empty array, but you might modified `moviesArr` somewhere that is not posted.

Comment: @MikeCAT The 4 times the program touches the moviesArr are posted here. I just did a search with control F on the code itself and everything to do with movies is here. The whole code is almost 700 lines, as it searches books, and music, as well as sorts, adds and and swaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
Movies moviesArr[ARR_SIZE];
```

defines an empty, uninitialized array of `Movies`. You are searching for a particular `Movie` `title` in `hollywood`, which finds the movie. However, you are then indexing `moviesArr`:

```
 cout << "The movie: " << moviesArr[pos].getTitle() << " is in the list. " << endl;
```

which is undefined behaviour (and printed nothing for the title in your case).

Replace that with:

```
 cout << "The movie: " << hollywood[pos].getTitle() << " is in the list. " << endl;
```